# how to change button colour in adf forms dynamically?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to change my button background color dynamically when there is no data in next page or form?please help me.i am using jdeveloper 11g

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change the background color? Instead you can make the button as disabled if there is no data.

Comment: no my client wants to change the button color,u know how to do,please help

Answer (score 0):

Put a conditional EL in the styleclass attribute of the button and refer to a style you defined in your skin:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/styling_specific_adf_components_with